# Magento Show Specific product on cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I want to show two configurable products on a cms page. The two products are under a sub category (id = 343). I've used below code in my cms page:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="home.catalog.product.list" 
alias="products_homepage" category_id="343"  product_count="2" 
template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but it gives this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in
>   /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/sm_sport/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
>   on line 38

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your type is wrong, try `catalog/product_list`?
Or do you want to show the products individually?

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="343"             template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Alternatively you could use XML on the CMS page?

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <!-- Product List View -->
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>343</category_id></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just use this

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="343"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

That should do the trick, you don´t need the product_count as it will just show all and if there are only 2 then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use widget Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_count="2" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`343`;]]"}}
```